# COPY invalid byte sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sometimes when I COPY a file into database like:

```
COPY tmp(champ1, champ2, champ3) FROM '/var/www/site/my_file.csv' WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8'
```

I encountered:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"
```

for a character or another.

How can I make the COPY import anyway without enter into the file and change the character manualy ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you know what encoding the file is you are trying to copy? You will need to tell copy to convert from that

Comment: Most of the times, the files are in ISO-something but never exacty the same. I need an auto conversion

Comment: is this on a script ? if yes, check the file's encoding and mount the copy line accordingly.

Comment: @Macbernie The whole concept of "automatically" detecting and converting encoding is broken. You can *guess* the encoding, but there is *no way to know* if the guess is right. At best, your guess can be confirmed not to produce any obviously invalid results, but that doesn't mean the text is actually what it should be rather than some garbled mess.